# Hiding cells in columns when the value is zero

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, hidden

Edit: I should clarify what I was trying to do. I have a list of values in column D through H and sometimes I may not have any values in the top most rows (they then equal 0, usually 40 rows or so). I want to make it so I don't have to scroll down to the rows that do have values not equaling zero. So I thought it would be easiest to hide the rows that have values equaling zero. But I have values in column A that I don't want to hide. I didn't realize I couldn't hide rows in a specific column without hiding the whole row. I need to rethink how I want to do this.

Original post: I am new to VBA, please bear with me. I have been copy and pasting different snippets of code, trying to get something to work.

I want to loop through all cells in column D through H and have the cells that equal zero to hide themselves. I plan on reusing this sheet so I want the cells to unhide themselves when the value is above zero again.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Hide_Cells_If_zero()`enter code here`

Dim targetRange As Range, po As Long, i As Long
Set targetRange = Columns("D:H")
po = targetRange.Count

With targetRange
For i = 1 To po
    If .Cells(i, 1).Value = 0 Then
    .Rows(i).Hidden = True
    End If
Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't see your goal: Do you want to hide columns or rows? You can't hide individual cells. `For i = 1 to po` will count to many: You use it as a row index but po will be the number of cells in D:H, so 5 × number of rows.

Comment: I want to hide the rows in those columns that have values that equal 0

Comment: I don't get an error, its just not hiding all the rows in the columns that I laid out.

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Rows With Criteria

- This will hide each row where the value of any cell in columns `D:H` evaluates to `0`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Hide_Cells_If_zero()

    Dim sRng As Range
    Set sRng = Columns("D:H")

    Dim tRng As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each rRng In sRng.Rows
        For Each cel In rRng.Cells
            If cel.Value = 0 Then
                If Not tRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set tRng = Union(tRng, cel)
                Else
                    Set tRng = cel
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    Next rRng

    If Not tRng Is Nothing Then
        tRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This does work for me thank you. Is there anyway to hide rows in those specific columns or will it always effect the whole row?

Comment: I don't want to delete the rows because they are place holders for results that may be referenced there at any time. I need to rethink how I want to do this.

Comment: The delete part is useless because the rows will be shifting up. You might consider maybe copying them to another worksheet since I'm assuming that not all the cells are blank.

Comment: I think I know how I will make this work. I will just have the top cells that equal 0 shift to columns to the right and then the cells that do not equal 0 will shift up. And then based on the values those cells reference, they may shift back.